# how to move a bitmap on canvas slowly using sensors

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, sensors

i want to move a bitmap on canvas using sensors and i am able to do this but the problem is that its moving too fast and i need to tilt the phone to very large extent so how can i decrease the movement of bitmap and decrease the amount of tilt to move the ball 
here is my code 
please help i am new to android

```
public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }
            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();
            canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            Rect red = new Rect(0, canvasHeight / 2, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
            Paint Pred = new Paint();
            Pred.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawRect(red, Pred);
            ballY = (canvasHeight-ballheight) + sensorX* 100;
            ballX = (canvasWidth-ballwidth) + sensorY* 70;
            ballY=ballY-ballheight/2;
            ballX=ballX-ballwidth/2;
            cheakBoundaries();
            checkIsWin();
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball, ballX, ballY, null);
            Paint Pblack = new Paint();
            Pblack.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            Paint Pwhite = new Paint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(16);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Pwhite.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawCircle(canvasWidth/2, 0, ballwidth,Pblack);
            canvas.drawCircle(canvasWidth/2,canvasHeight,ballwidth, Pwhite);
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sensorY = event.values[0];
        sensorX = event.values[1];
    }
}
```